# Excel: SUMIF refered to dynamic range

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to write a SUMIF formula with reference to dynamic columns.

Here an example.

In the cell G7, I need to have the sum of the number related to Mark (row 3) from the column stored in the cell D3 (in this case H) to the column stored in the cell D4 (in this case L). The result of this formula gives the number 7 in cell G7 and the number 8 in G8.

**I would like to manage this issue without using VBA if possible.**

I thought at something like:

```
G7 = =SUMIF(F:F;F7;<the value stored in D3>:<the value stored in D4>)
```

I hope to have explained the issue well.

[image]

Comment: @ScottCraner yes sorry!! I will change the pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple sum with two INDEX/MATCH will do it:

```
=SUM(INDEX($1:$10000,MATCH(F7,F:F,0),CODE(UPPER($D$3))-64):INDEX($1:$4,MATCH(F7,F:F,0),CODE(UPPER($D$4))-64))
```

On note, this will only work till column Z, if you data is past that we will need to find something different than the `CODE(UPPER($D$3))-64` to denote the column extents.

We would need to use INDIRECT, which if can be avoided, should. It should be avoided because it is volatile.  So if your data goes past column Z then use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(INDIRECT($D$3&":"&$D$3),MATCH(F7,F:F,0)):INDEX(INDIRECT($D$4&":"&$D$4),MATCH(F7,F:F,0)))
```

[image]